# Centering the map depends on the markers in Angular OpenLayers directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, openlayers, angular-openlayers

I use [Angular-openlayers-directive by tombatossals](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive) . Is there a way to center the map depending on the markers?

Answer (score 0):

Create Bounds from markers (first marker Coordinates and Last Marker Coordinates) and use it like as-

```
center {
    extent: [ 0, 0, 51.505, -0.09 ]
}
```

For More reference see this link https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive/blob/master/doc/02-center-attribute.md

Comment: @shailedra How to get the coordinates of of a point using this directive?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36435689/how-to-get-coordinates-on-double-click-on-openstreetmap

Comment: @dilpeshjain What are you using, marker coordinates or direct address  to show on map?.

Comment: @ShailendraSinghDeol I need the coordinates of the point where I click ,using this directive.